# Fridge/cooler circuit unnecessary diodes

Tags: diodes, peltier

I am modifying a mini cooler/heater to turn it into an incubator in which I can program the temperature sequence in time. I have reconstructed the electric diagram of the cooler/heater and I don't understand why the maker chose to include the circled diodes. Here is the diagram:
[image: Mini cooler/heater diagram, a switch controls whether it works as a cooler or heater]

There is a switch which controls whether the heater works as a cooler or as a heater, resulting in the two different wirings shown in the figure.

I don't understand why the maker used the circles diodes, being that the following diagram should do the same job, without needing the diodes:
[image: Simpler diagram, this should do the same job without needing the diodes]

The wiring would be as in the figure above, depending on whether it's a cooler or a heater.

My question is: is there a reason to prefer the maker's design to the one I propose?

Comment: Good point. Maybe there was a third position in which everything was off? Also, why the resistor?

Comment: The diodes are for the fan. They ensure that whichever way the switch is connected, the fan still gets power, and also allows for an off position where nothing runs.

Comment: That's it, I didn't think about the OFF position, which is the third option for the switch. Thank you!

Comment: Uhh your circuit won't work because you can't put a resistor before the fan. The fan motor just won't work.